# how fix memory leaks from Valgrind log

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, patch

This is the first time i have seen a valgrind log  , this log is provided by other users (i can't run valgrind , since it's not supported stlinux (sh4)

for learning how could fix memory leak with valgrind log , would highly appreciated if any expert , choose even one line of bellow's valgrind error log (and tell us , the valgrind error line he intends for fix  and post their fix (patch of source code)

then , would learn how we could fix memory leak from valgrind log , and i would do all rest fixing myself (i just need a example fix)

here is the app trac browser (source code) :
http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/browser/trunk/?rev=5375

would highly appreciate if any expert would take a look at these log (i really need help) , here are 4 valgrind logs :

[http://www.4shared.com/office/04seUumN/valgrind_*2*.html](http://www.4shared.com/office/04seUumN/valgrind__2_.html)

http://www.4shared.com/office/WYmfxICb/valgrindlog.html

http://www.4shared.com/office/WGwlKeUK/valgrind.html

[http://www.4shared.com/office/mkX4FAzd/valgrind_*1*.html](http://www.4shared.com/office/mkX4FAzd/valgrind__1_.html)

P.S :

1. since i can't run valgrind myself  , please choose a memory leak with largest memory loss (leaks) , then , i could monitor those improvement with my eyes (top command , ps -aux)
2. my concern for fixing memory leaks , are mostly limited to these modules (for me the priority (importance) is in their number sequence ( i mean , fixing a memory leak with module-datastruct-list.c is in top priority for me , ....)

   - module-datastruct-list.c
   - oscam-garbage.c
   - oscam.c
   - module-cccam.c
   - module-dvbapi.c

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider compiling and debugging your application on a x86 Linux system, then, once it is debugged on Linux/x86, port it to your target sh4 embedded system?

Comment: @Basile , yes , i think it's not possible , i had read somewhere valgrind does not support sh4 cpu (there was so many attempt by other users to make valgrind work with sh4 , but they didn't succeed.  my question is , one expert be such a kind , and show me how he would fix one line of memory leak (from real valgrind logs ) then i would learn myself , and would fix valgrind logs myself

Comment: Try to compile and build your application on an x86 Linux system (perhaps writing stub functions for those specific to the target SH4 hardware), then debug it on x86/Linux.

Comment: @Basile  , it's not possible for me to run my application in X86 , This application is use in my stb (which is connected to Dvb-s , and in my pc i do not have the dvb-s hardware for X86 (i only have sh4 stb) , so i have to stick my stb (which is sh4) and i think our discussion is going off-topic , i didn't ask somebody help me to run valgrind with sh4 , i asked , someone do me a favor and show me how he would fix memory leaks from real valgrid logs (i had posted above)

Comment: Debugging a memory leak is a significant task, even with `valgrind` (because even `valgrind` don't tell the origin of the leak, it warns you later, only when it detects the leak). It may require a week of work for the author of the software. You cannot expect such a effort from forum contributors.

Comment: Yes , i know it might be a tough job (and also challenging) , but i am quite sure there are some super smart guys in this place (some really expert guys) who could take a look at those valgrind log , and fix one of them , and i would really appreciate and try any helpful idea for fixing.

Comment: No, even smart guys need a very deep knowledge of the buggy software with `valgrind` detected leaks. Your expectation is not realistic. The point is that `valgrind` will detect leaks much later than their origin! Aliveness of data is a whole program property.

Comment: @Basile So what is your solution , do u know any other tools better than valgrind for this purpose! Just to be or make disappointed and saying debugging memory leak us a significant task , i don't think this is the best answer . Regards

Comment: My suggestion is still to make the efforts to port your application on Linux/x86 (perhaps writing stub code for the functions which depend upon nonexistent or incompatible things), then debug it first there. Or else, study the valgrind logs by yourself. Or pay a subcontractor. Or don't use `malloc` (instead use `GC_malloc` from http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/ etc). But correcting a memory leak, even with the help of `valgrind`, requires full & deep knowledge of the software, and may takes weeks if you are unlucky, and hours if you are lucky. Don't expect us to work weeks for you.

Answer (score 2):

I used Valgrind a long time ago so I don't remember well how to use it, but I know it is fairly easy. Valgrind logs show every memory leak of the program, due to your code, but also due to code you call from libraries. For every leak, the function call stack is displayed, like this :

```
==5313== Invalid write of size 4
==5313==    at 0x8048A27: test_2() (valgrind-tests.cc:37)
==5313==    by 0x8048CDF: main (valgrind-tests.cc:134)
==5313==    by 0x215BBE: __libc_start_main (in /lib/libc-2.3.2.so)
==5313==    by 0x8048910: (within /home/newren/examples/valgrind-tests)
==5313==    Address 0x1B3E024 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==5313==    at 0x5419C5: __builtin_delete (vg_replace_malloc.c:244)
==5313==    by 0x5419E3: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:253)
==5313==    by 0x8048A20: test_2() (valgrind-tests.cc:36)
==5313==    by 0x8048CDF: main (valgrind-tests.cc:134)
==5313==    by 0x215BBE: __libc_start_main (in /lib/libc-2.3.2.so)
==5313==    by 0x8048910: (within /home/newren/examples/valgrind-tests)
```

This means you try to write 4 bytes in memory, but you don't have access to theses bytes.
This issue is located at line 37 of "valgrind-tests.cc" in this example.

The main problem of valgrind is that, as I said earlier, it displays memory leaks or memory warnings (like forgotten pointers) from libraries you use.
To clean your logs, you can write valgrind rule files called "[suppression files](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.suppfiles)".

More informations [here](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) and [here](http://people.gnome.org/~newren/tutorials/developing-with-gnome/html/ch03s03.html).